# import AlgoliaSearch with Swift 2 causing error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, algolia

Adding this line to my App *import AlgoliaSearch* returns this error:

> 2017-05-08 22:35:07.814593 XXXXXX[6255:2627487] -[__NSDictionaryI
>   length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1702f0980 2017-05-08
>   22:35:07.816565 XXXXXX[6255:2627487] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSDictionaryI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x1702f0980'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x192f351b8 0x19196c55c 0x192f3c268 0x192f39270 0x192e3280c 0x1015c8608 0x10158d72c 0x10194a198
>   0x1001f6c24 0x1001f8c9c 0x100091fd4 0x1003973d4 0x100397690
>   0x1003be2c0 0x101a5d258 0x101a5d218 0x101a62280 0x192ee2810
>   0x192ee03fc 0x192e0e2b8 0x1948c2198 0x198e557fc 0x198e50534
>   0x10013c734 0x191df15b8) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException (lldb)

The line of code it is referring to is as below:

```
self.ref.child("users").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

    for user in snapshot.children{
        var numVids = NSDictionary()
        if ((user.hasChild("videos")) == true){
   -->    numVids = user.value["videos"] as! NSDictionary
        }

    }
```

As soon as I remove the import Algolia module the error is removed, I have tried changing the version of the module and even switching to use the objc version but the error was the same.

Anyone seen something like this before?

https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-swift

https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-objc

Comment: are you sure that user.value["videos"] is a Dictionary not String?
Can you post the data structure to this question ?

Comment: Yep, the same line works as intended when the Algolia module in not added. Here is an example of the data: 
`Snap (XXXX) {
    avatar = “path/to/image”;
    bio = “User bio here..! ";
    category = “Blog”;
    email = “email@gmail”;
    name = “User Name”;
    videos =     {
        “LONG-ID-HERE“ = "1485288673.82";
        “LONg-ID-HERE” = "1486655595.68705";
    };
    };
}`

Comment: Couple of questions in order to understand more: 
1- When you put a breakpoint at the crashing line, what do you see for the `videos` values? are you sure it is an `NSDictionary`? 
2- I don't see an obvious reason why adding `import AlgoliaSearch` will give you an `unrecognized selector` error. What version of AlgoliaSearch you're using? The latest one uses Swift 3, and you seem to be using Swift 2 in your project, so there might be something going on there. which lead me to question 3: 
3- Were you able to use the `AlgoliaSearch` successfully in your project elsewhere?

Comment: Its really strange - The breakpoint shows the videos as nil but when I build and run without AlgoliaSearch it is not nil and works again. It is version 3.7 & yep i'm using Swift 2 in the project.

Comment: I see..  but is it only `user.value["videos"] that is nil or the whole `user` response that is nil? and what about question 3, were you able to use AlgoliaSearch elsewhere? You seem to be using Firebase here, and maybe _somehow_, ` `AlgoliaSearch` is interfering with the request of Firebase, although I currently don't have a guess now. The best way for me to help you is if you can post a snippet of code so that I can reproduce the bug on my side. Like that I can investigate and try to find the root cause. We can also move the conversation to a [Github Issue](https://git.io/v96xf) if you want!